# Cannot convert from int[] to int?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, int

im new to programming in general, I've been trying to build a system in java for my comp sci course and I'm getting the error "cannot convert from int[] to int" in eclipse.

```
public static ArrayList<Book> CreateBooksArrayList(){
    int[] id = {1,2,3,4,5};
    String[] bookTitle = {"book1", "book2", "book3", "book4", "book5"};
    String[] authorName = {"author1", "author2", "author3", "author4", "author5"};
    double[] bookReleaseYear = {123,456,789,987,654};
    int[] numOnLoan = {1,2,2,3,4};
    int[] numInStock = {5,5,5,5,5};


    int bID = -1;
    String bTitle = null;
    String aName = null;
    double bRelease = -1;
    int nLoan = -1;
    int nStock = -1;

    ArrayList<Book> Books = new ArrayList<Book>();
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++){
        bID = id[i];
        bTitle = bookTitle[i];
        aName = authorName[i];
        bRelease = bookReleaseYear[i];
        nLoan = numOnLoan;
        nStock = numInStock;
        Books.add(new Book(bID, bTitle, aName, bRelease, nLoan, nStock));
```

I've tried searching for an answer, but i cant seem to find any links with this exact problem. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you think the error means  based on the message alone?

Comment: You forgot the `[i]` section when setting your `nLoan` and `nStock`. Should be `nLoan = numOnLoan[i];`

Comment: I think it seems as if its an issue related to using an int array and an int, but i cant think of how to fix it

Comment: Thanks Gonzo, ill give that a try :)

Comment: Thank you so much! such a silly mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `[i]` section for `numOnLoan` and `numInStock` in your for loop. Change them both to include the `[i]`.

```
nLoan = numOnLoan[i];
nStock = numInStock[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
nLoan = numOnLoan;
nStock = numInStock;
```

with :

```
nLoan = numOnLoan[i];
nStock = numInStock[i];
```

Comment: Thanks Berger! i cant believe i didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change these lines:

```
    nLoan = numOnLoan;
    nStock = numInStock;
```

With these you forgot the index `i` of loop to retrieve the value from array:

```
    nLoan = numOnLoan[i];
    nStock = numInStock[i];
```

Comment: Thank you Abdelhak, just adding the [i] to the numOnLoan and numInStock fixed it